# Simple errors from getInfoByClass?

Tags: javascript, debugging, applescript

I am trying to get some info off of a website using AppleScript and I keep getting "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier." errors that highlight JavaScript

Heres the section of faulty code

```
to getInputByClass(theClass, num)

    tell application "Google Chrome" 

        set input to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 

    end tell

    return input

end getInputByClass
```

I have also tried and failed using

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set theScript to "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
    do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

My whole code(very short) is now as seen below.  I cannot get the code to post the info it is getting from the javascript into column b. What would you do to fix that. Once again thank you.

set i to 1

repeat 725 times

```
activate application "Microsoft Excel"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    select cell ("a" & (i as string))
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 1
end tell

activate application "Google Chrome"

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using command down
    delay 1
    keystroke "https://bookscouter.com/prices.php?isbn="
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke "&searchbutton=Sell"
    delay 1
    keystroke return
    delay 10
end tell

set theText to getInputByClass("book-prices", 0)
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set value of cell ("b" & (i as string)) to theText
end tell

set i to i + 1

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "w" using command down
end tell
```

end repeat

to getInputByClass(theClass, num)

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of window 1
        set input to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
    end tell
end tell

return input
```

end getInputByClass

Answer (score 0):

Take a look inside the Scripting Dictionary. There is no `do javascript`-handler defined for *Google Chrome*. You will find `execute` instead:

```
to getInputByClass(theClass, num)

    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of window 1
            set input to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
        end tell
    end tell

    return input

end getInputByClass
```

If you call this handler on this side with

```
getInputByClass("current-site-link site-link js-gps-track", 0)
```

you should get

```
<div class=\"site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflow\" title=\"Stack Overflow\"></div>
            Stack Overflow
```

as result.

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg